# Libcurl openSSL certificate problem (c++)

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate, libcurl, pem

I am writing a program in C++ and now there is a need for cross-platform and dependency adjustment. While I was writing for linux, everything was OK, but I started to port the code to Windows. My program needs licurl. first I compiled through nmake - the wö learned the code worked. However, I need Cmake for the task. So I slightly edited CmakeLists compiled without SSL, which was fixed by compiling openSSL. And then there was a mistake that I'm not ready for at all:

```
* Trying 172.67.163.127:443...
* Connected to www.showmyip.com (172.67.163.127) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

I found out from OpenSSL --version that I have certificates registered along the way Z:\extlib_openssl111__\ssl there was no such disk, so I used a USB flash drive to create this path. Then I tried to export the certificate from the browser (pem). Created in the folder Z:\extlib_openssl111__\ssl folder [www.showmyip.com](http://www.showmyip.com) and exported the ssl dir certificate there and to the root - it didn't help. Then I command:

```
 openssl s_client -connect showmyip.com:443 -showcerts > stackoverflow.txt
```

This merged 3 certificates into an odil file and I really don't know what to do with it.

OpenSSL can be run with a derivative:

```
 -CAfile demoCA/cacert.pem
```

but I have another case I can't run openssl.exe , I'm accessing libcurl and libcrypto directly, maybe it can somehow be written in the C++ code if you throw an example, I will be very grateful.

Comment: I solved the problem by abandoning openssl in favor of set(USE_SCHANNEL ON) - native windows ssl

Comment: Update! I solve the same problem on termux! When building libcurl source it need to open top CmakeLists.txt and find "set(SEARCH_CA_BUNDLE_PATHS "and set full path to certs(i mean full as /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt), then build clean. after that it was error of adding cert because its link in cert file. i copy text of linking cert to my that is in path and every thing works great!!!))))